# database:how to do math operation on tables

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on survey and trying to do the following using database

sum the options based on specific category

```
option_no in "answer" table
```

then divide the sum on number of the question in each category

```
question_num in "category" table
```

finally store result on *score* and *score2* column in *"user_servey"* table

here is
[my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmOvH.png)

**Dose anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a try.

Join the tables, group the output and add the aggregation, then derive the answer and write it into user_survey:

```
insert into user_survey
select a.user_id, s.survey_id,
  sum(option_no)/sum(question_num) as score, 
  sum(option_no)/sum(question_num) as score2
from answer a join questions q on a.question_id = q.question_id
join category c on q.category_id = c.category_id 
join survey s on q.question_id = s.question_id
group by a.user_id, s.survey_id
```

Apologies if my logic is wrong, your description is really not very clear and I can't try this because you have broken the guidelines by not providing your actual CREATE TABLE statements.

Comment: thank you for your effort actually..it's work as the following i have questions each question belong to category..so i add the number of questions that belong to category.. I assume the  question_num is already add in database..just i sum user option sum(option_no) and then divide it on (question_num) @MandyShaw

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't make head or tail of that ... maybe you could explain the business requirement? That would help.

Comment: well..the business requirement is assume that i have multiple survives each survey has multiple questions so the user after select one survey has to fill some information before start then move to the question..one of these survey has different approach which is  all its questions classified in category after user  complete this survey he will receive the calculated result via the entered email and the beginning the result is sum of option of category /numbre of question on it @MandyShaw

Comment: for ex: if i have categories : cat1,cat2,cat3.. *cat1* contain 3 questions and *cat1:*contain 2 question  *cat1:*contain 4 questions..assume questions (1,2,3,5)belong to cat 1 and questions(6,7)belong to cat 2 so the result will be as the following sum the user selected option value so if user answer for questions of cat (2,2,3) it will be 2+2+3/question number in cat1 which is 3 then store the each result in user_serevy  table as score ,score 1 etc depending  on how many category that i have @MandyShaw

Comment: I'm really sorry but I still can't work this out. It would probably help if you put some punctuation in, honestly. Also, does my example not help you in terms of working out an approach? Remember that we're not here to do your coding for you. (My reading of your most recent comment still doesn't make the logic in my answer feel definitely wrong.)